# How to unit test MVC controller that uses HttpContext in ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have this small method written in ASP.Net Core on .Net Core 1.1 framework:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("SchemaName");
        HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

I am struggling a lot with how to write a unit test that verifies that this method returns a `RedirectToActionResult` and tried many different approaches based on both old and relative new information found here and there. The problem is that `HttpContext` is `null` and I have been unsuccessful in mocking it.

Any help in writing this test would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can setup a controller with an instance of the `DefaultHttpContext` like in this helper function.

```
    public MyController CreateController()
    {            
        var actionContext = new ActionContext
        {
            HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(),
            RouteData = new RouteData(),
            ActionDescriptor = new ControllerActionDescriptor()
        };

        var controller = new MyController
        {
            ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(actionContext)
        };

        return controller;
    }
```

Then the `HttpContext` property of the MyController instance is not `null` anymore and it provides a default `AuthenticationManager` in the `HttpContext.Authentication` property.